# bad argument #1 to 'gmatch' (string expected, got nil)

Tags: lua

```
function splitString(str,symbol)
    local number = 1
    local tableResult = {}

    if symbol == nil then
        symbol = "-"
    end

    for str in string.gmatch(str,"([^"..symbol.."]+)") do
        tableResult[number] = str
        number = number + 1
    end

    return tableResult
end
```

I'm not an experienced "scripter" so i can't really figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

`str` is a nil value, not a string. When you call `splitstring` the first argument is nil. Make sure it is a string or don't call the function with it.